# How to add custom content after the tab section (and before "you may also like..." section) in woocommerce single product page?

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

[screenshot of what i am trying to say](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJjIb.png) I want to add some text and pictures after the tab section and before "you may also like..." section in a woocommerce single product page.

I got to know about two hooks:

> woocommerce_after_single_product_summary
>
> woocommerce_after_single_product

but in both cases, content is adding after "you may also like..." section

I tried this below code but text in showing after "you may also like..." section.

```
function add_text_in_between(){
 echo 'i want to show immediately after tab section but  before "you may also like..." section';
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product', 'add_text_in_between');
```

Comment: i cant get your mean. please make me clear with adding screenshot to your question.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I found the answer :

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_after_tabs', 'add_text_in_between', 20);
```

this hook is not documented

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'product_custom_content', 10);

function product_custom_content() {
    
    echo 'Your Content area';
    
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.